# How to print/export a QTreeWidget content?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

Assuming I have a QTreeWidget like that

[image: Print QTreeWidget]

I tried this code to Print/Export this QTreeWidget to a file (The name of this QTreeWidget is **trvListVehicle**)

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&printer);

double xscale = printer.pageRect().width() / double(ui->trvListVehicle->width());
double yscale = printer.pageRect().height() / double(ui->trvListVehicle->height());
double scale = qMin(xscale, yscale);
painter.translate(printer.paperRect().x() + printer.pageRect().width()/2,
                  printer.paperRect().y() + printer.pageRect().height()/2);
painter.scale(scale, scale);
painter.translate(-width()/2, -height()/2);

ui->trvListVehicle->render(&painter);
```

The program shows Print dialog for me to choose printer machine. After printing completely, I got a **blank page**. The page didn’t contain any content.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_print_a_widget

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `printer` returns an empty `pageRect()`. Maybe you need to select a `paperSize()`, since that is driver dependent...

Try to display some info, for instance with `qDebug() << printer.pageRect()`, that can easily be redirected to file...

Answer (score 0):

Asi me funcionó a mi, suerte!

```
QPrinter printer;
QPainter painter;
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setOutputFileName("nonwritable.pdf");
painter.begin(&printer);
painter.translate(printer.paperRect().x() + printer.pageRect().width(),
                            printer.paperRect().y() + printer.pageRect().height());
         painter.scale(1, 1);
         painter.translate(-width()/2, -height());

         ui->treeWidget->render(&painter);
```